# Publishing ASMX webservice visualstudio 2022 with two webreferences ,one is missing after publishing

Tags: publish, asmx

I am adding a new  webmethod in  a vb.net ASMX webservice,for this I need  to add new web service references ,one to send an email and other to get data from back end.
so I have Webservice1,webservice2,Webservice 3 in total.
Webservice2&3 are referred to webservice1.
When I am debugging the whole functionality works fine,testing was success.
Web.config has following

```
**<myproject.My.MySettings>
     <setting name="webservice1" serializeAs="String">
       <value>http:webservice1path.asmx</value>
     </setting>
    <setting name="webservice2" serializeAs="String">
    <value>https:webservice2path.asmx</value>
   </setting>
 </myproject.My.MySettings>**
```

Initially this webservice was developed with dotnet framework 4.0,now I am using 4.8 to modify.

**Problem with publishing:**

While publishing in a filefolder,I see only webservice1(main webservice) bin ,asmx,dlls,none of the other webservices references were added to the published folder.sometimes I see webservice 2 folder with reference.map and  if I publish another time even that misses out.
webservice 2 is never added to the published folder

Am I publishing correctly?

Plz help